# Popup Nuget for xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Any Nuget for popups in `Xamarin.Forms` ? Even with the latest update of `Rg.Plugin.Popup` the popup's are crashing on iOS 13 devices !

Comment: Try this ones `Arc.UserDialogs`: github: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs and `nuget`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/459

Please close the VS and run

> dotnet nuget locals all --clear

in a terminal. After it restart your mac and check it.